# VS 2015 Keeps Crashing at random

Tags: visual-studio-2015

So I can't open VS 2015 unless I do so in safe mode. If I don't, I just get a something has caused this application to stop working properly error. If I open a project in safe mode and work for a while, it still will randomly crash with the same error. Here's what I've found in the windows event log.

Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 14.0.23107.0, time stamp: 0x559b7ead
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18007, time stamp: 0x55c4bcfc
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x00015b68
Faulting process id: 0x37b8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d139034e3378dd
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 28d0db8b-a4f9-11e5-802a-f01faf32f733
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

And there is a .net error right before that.

Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException
Stack:
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c__DisplayClass2.b__3(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)

Any ideas as to what is going on and how I can troubleshoot or fix the issue??

Comment: Have you tried standard troubleshooting steps? Reintall .Net, reinstall VS, make sure you have the latest patches and updates for VS. Also

Comment: This question is better suited to [su], since it involves debugging an error with a closed-source program (I'm not so sure the 'IDE questions are allowed on Stack Overflow' exception applies here).

Comment: @cybermonkey : Since it is a "IDE crashes" question rather then a "how do I use the IDE" question, I think you are right we are here to help with the creation of code, not the debugging of Microsoft's code.

Comment: This question is [being discussed on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312790/are-questions-about-debugging-ides-on-topic).

Comment: The problem I have with closing this question is that within 38 minutes of it being asked, and maybe 10 to 15 views, close and migration is discussed. Without enough experienced developers with VS2015 seeing or commenting on it.

Comment: @Drew It's a configuration error with Visual Studio or that something is missing. The answer for this type of question is always going to be 'reset all settings or reinstall if that doesn't help'.

Comment: That is a strong statement to make: *always* . Can we close your comment (and mine too) as Primarily Opinion Based :P

Comment: For all of you saying reinstall vs or .net, I've reinstalled VS. .net 4.5 is a core component of win 8 so you can't uninstall it. You can "turn the feature off" but I'm pretty sure that doesn't uninstall it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095134/visual-studio-is-acting-weird-how-do-i-fix-this

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens when you mess around with certain options, OR it could happen after installing an update to VS. Follow these steps in 'safe mode':

Go to Tools -> Import and Export Settings... -> Reset all settings

Make sure you keep the backup option selected so you can revert back if you need to.

Comment: Trying to help the guy and I get downvoted?

Comment: The down vote was harsh, and deserved an explanatory comment perhaps, but the question is clearly not in scope for SO, so your suggestion would have better been posted as an comment perhaps, so you can help without appearing to encourage questions inappropriate to SO.

Comment: @Clifford Still new to SO so I guess I did not realize it was a bad question. I should go over the rules... thanks for explaining. Appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a settings issue, as we have one guy who does VS settings for our entire dev team, then exports them and we import them. We have 5 other devs running the same settings with no issue. I have opened a ticket with MS, if they find the cause, I'll post the solution.