# Unable to start debugging verify debug settings for startup project VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

This message keeps showing when i press debug.

How do i fix it so i can debug.

I have had the project for a couple of weeks so its not new and it has been working normally.

Im running Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise as shown in title

Here is the message:

[image]

Comment: maybe you have no selected startup project? try to right click on the project you want to run and select "set as startup project".

Comment: I would suggest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095134/visual-studio-is-acting-weird-how-do-i-fix-this but I know it doesn't work.  The only thing that works is to restart visual studio.  This happened to me just this morning.  It's a big PITA.

Comment: i restarted it and it works

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Restart Visual studio
this is all i did and it worked fine.

Comment: What a solution :))) Worked for me too :)