# ClickOnce Publishing in Visual Studio 2017 RC not available

Tags: visual-studio-2017

When installing Visual Studio 2017RC, I already included the required Component in the installation:

[image]

Although when opening the "Publish" Page in the Project-Settings, its not available.

[image]

What am i missing?

Comment: "You need to reinstall Visual Studio to publish your application"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio is acting weird. How do I fix this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095134/visual-studio-is-acting-weird-how-do-i-fix-this)

Comment: I had big problems with this. Turns out that having Visual Studio 2008 installed was the problem. I uninstalled it and everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be there in RTM bits.

[image]