# Quick Actions and Refactorings not working in VS2015 Pro

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

[image]

For all uses of the Quick Actions and Refactoring in VS2015 Pro, I'm getting this error popup.  I've attempted the usual Google-foo on this, and have yet to find a solution that works.  Has anyone else come across this or have any ideas on a fix?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095134/visual-studio-is-acting-weird-how-do-i-fix-this

Comment: lol I love this thread, upvote just for the writing style there.  I'll give these a shot, I already did the repair and that didn't fix it so I suppose I'll uninstall/reinstall.  Thanks Will!

Comment: Good luck, dude.  If you can make any improvements to that question/answer (something you tried that wasn't covered, for example), feel free to improve.

Comment: The uninstall/reinstall fixed it.  The basic repair did not, so I'm guessing I had a config file somewhere that was not overwritten/replaced by the repair.