# Visual Studio 2017 Nuget Client Version off

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I installed Visual Studio 2017 last night.  This morning when I open up an existing Web Api project, I am seeing this:

> C:\MyProject.nuget\NuGet.targets(92,9): error : The
>   'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights 2.2.0' package requires NuGet client
>   version '2.8.50313' or above, but the current NuGet version is
>   '2.7.41115.310'.

This is happening on nine different packages: Bcl, .NET.Http, etc...

Any insight?

Thanks

Comment: 1) Extensions and updates -> check the updates tab 2) reinstall VS from the web 3) uninstall all versions of visual studio and do 2 again

Comment: Interesting.  I installed 2017 and then removed 2015.  Must have screwed up nuget...

Comment: Did you reinstall to fix?

Comment: Yes - that did it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio is acting weird. How do I fix this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095134/visual-studio-is-acting-weird-how-do-i-fix-this)