# Visual Studio 2015 cant access Extensions and Updates

Tags: visual-studio

Upon trying to access extensions and Updates, I am confronted by this error message.

Tools > Extensions and Updates..

How does one resolve this issue?

[image]

(Using Visual Studio 2015)

Comment: Usually this kind of problem is not "fixable".  Your only recourse is typically to uninstall and re-install.  Even then, sometimes corrupted registry info can stick around, and you may be forced to wipe your hard drive and re-install the OS and your tools to get things working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio is acting weird. How do I fix this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095134/visual-studio-is-acting-weird-how-do-i-fix-this)

Answer (score 0):

So i was using VS 2015. I just uninstalled it, and because I was on subscription, I installed VS 2017. Now everything is working.