# Visual Studio 2017 does not start

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have been running VS 2017 for a month or so now and have had no issues until today. But now I cant get it to open it just closes again when clicking the icon.

When I opened it this morning I got an error message

> A problem has occurred when loading the Microsoft visual studio menu. To fix this problem, run 'devenv.exe/resetsettings from the command prompt.

I did this now when I go to open I get the visual studio popup window but just closes and nothing happens.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled with no joy

Any one come across this before or have a fix for it?

Comment: Uninstall/reinstall?  Or a repair?

Comment: Sorry to add I did uninstall and reinstall it worked for a hour or so closed it and the same has happened again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095134/visual-studio-is-acting-weird-how-do-i-fix-this Did you run 'devenv.exe /resetsettings from the command prompt?

Comment: Yea I did no joy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case is  I updated windows 10 using "windows 10 update assistant" and after updating I tried to open visual studio 2017, it worked!...

Answer (score 9):

Run "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017" and use "devenv" or "devenv /SafeMode" command. This will work 9 out of 10 times.

[See this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VH1Lw.png)

FYI, I tried opening VS 2017 with Run as Admin but it works only for first time and fails other times.

Badly awaiting fix from MS!

Answer (score 1):

Right-click and "Run as Administrator" worked for me.

The problem of the VS not launching started happening for me as well since the last couple of patches.  It wouldn't even bring up the splash screen, but you could see devenv.exe running in Task Manager.

I am running VS Enterprise 2017 with patch 15.3.4.

Answer (score 1):

In my case Visual Studio 2017 began to start-up minimized by default on my notebook.  No way to pop it out.  Finally, I was able to fix this by unplugging my external monitor and plugin it back again.  Hope this can help some of you…

Answer (score -1):

This may be because your trial period has expired.