# Visual Studio Enterprise Installer 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I upgraded Visual Studio Enterprise to version 15.6.4 and now the Installer is coming up saying it needs elevated privileges (which I already have) and says oops there is a problem all the time. Anyone else getting this issue? If so, has anyone discovered a fix or work around for this issue?

Thanks
Russ

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio is acting weird. How do I fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095134/visual-studio-is-acting-weird-how-do-i-fix-this)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, as my visual studio enterprise 2017 is working fine. When I go to update or change it through the installer, it doesn't work.

Comment: The installer is part of the overall system. Uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: Hi Will. It won't uninstall as that uses the installer that is not working.Have downloaded Enterprise 2015 right now and that is working fine, as I am at a loss what to do with 2017.

Comment: The installer won't uninstall? You're boned. You will have to scour MSDN for instructions for manual removal. Perhaps open a Connect if you can't find any. If you do find instructions, and you manage to nuke it manually and the reinstall works correctly, add the steps you took as an answer.  Good luck!

Comment: Yes that's what I will be doing in my spare time between using 2015 (which isn't too bad). Cheers for the advice. I will post a solution here IF I find it.