# Visual Studio 2017 - Cant view variables when in debug mode

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2017, ide

I have been trying to figure this problem out for a while now.

I work in Visual Studio 2017 and have many solutions I work on.  Every single one of them shows me variables and their values when I am debugging it except one.  It runs perfectly tho.

What I have done:

- Played around with managed compatibility mode
- Clean and rebuild and all those basics
- Remove local solution and get it fresh from Git

  - The other developers working on the same solution do not have this problem
- Tried debugging the solution in VS2015 and VS2019 Preview

Cant seem to fix this, any ideas on what more I can try?

**Edit**: Clarification, I can step through the code when debugging, but I cant view value of variables.

**EditEdit**: Was doing some testing, and I have new information. While one a breakpoint I look at a few variables.

- public ActionResult Detail(Guid? id) > I can view the value of id
- SomeObject item = someobjectRepository.GetItem(id).SingleOrDefault() > Gets the item but cant view its variables
- Later in the code foreach(var subitem in item.Subitems) > I can view the values of subitem.

**EditEditEdit**

Variables that cannot be view all have become stale.

For testing puroses I removed all the variables of my model so is completely empty then I initialize it

```
public MySuperModel()
{
}
```

Initialization

```
MySuperModel model = new MySuperModel();
```

Viewing model by either hovering or adding to watch/quickwatch yields the message that it has become stale.

And so forth, its very strange

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095134/visual-studio-is-acting-weird-how-do-i-fix-this reinstall.

Comment: I tried that :)  Also tried reinstalling 2015 and 2019

Comment: What's the project type?

Comment: Asp.net Web application.

Comment: Is the project being compiled in Release mode/with optimizations enabled in the project settings? This will rewrite the code in ways that makes *some* variables unavailable for inspection.

Comment: No its all debug mode, same settings as other project I work with.

Comment: Welp, when I find myself in a similar situation, I throw away the csproj file and re-create it from scratch. Tried that?

Comment: I did try removing everything locally and getting the project from scratch from Git, are you only talking about the actual csproj file?

Comment: Nuke the csproj, yes. Just remove it from the solution and from disk. Then add a new one with the same name and in the same location. Then you can add all the files back to he project and configure the project settings (assembly name, default namespace, bitness, etc).

Comment: Urghh!  Going to take a while but I'm on it. I'll report back.

Comment: Updated the description after a little more testing.

Comment: You are amazing @Ari Freyr! I ran into this same issue and I agree with your diagnosis and your solution did work for me. thank you!  I thought I was going crazy.

Comment: I am using VS 2022 and was debugging through my unit tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem, tho I dont know why it works.

I will try to explain.

I have a model that contains to IEnumerables.

**Model**

```
public SuperModel()
{
      public IEnumerable<MemberObject> memberList1{get; set;}
      public IEnumerable<MemberObject> memberList2{get; set;}
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Detail(Guid? id)
{
    //Model initialized
    SuperModel model =  GetTheModel();

    //Then there were 2 foreach loops throu my einumerables
    foreach(var item in model.memberList1)
    {
        //Do things
    }
    foreach(var item in model.memberList2)
    {
        //Do things
    }

}
```

This broke the debugger, If I only left 1 of the loops in debugger worked.

**Workaround**

```
public ActionResult Detail(Guid? id)
{
    //Model initialized
    SuperModel model =  GetTheModel();

    //Then there were 2 foreach loops throu my einumerables
    model.memberList1.ToList().Foreach((item) => 
    { 
        //Do Things
    });
    model.memberList2.ToList().Foreach((item) => 
    { 
        //Do Things
    });

}
```

**Fin**

I have no idea why using the .ForEach methods works while using a classic foearch() loop does not.  But if anyone runs into something like this I hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

[screenshot - not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHnIM.png)
[image: screenshot - not showing]

[screenshot - showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5n3OA.png)
[image: screenshot - showing]

```
List<ClassA> list = new List<ClassA>();
ClassA retVal = list.Where(o => o.MyProperty1 == 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Here will be no exception (error), **retVal** is **null** and you will not see the properties or the values of the properties of the class.

All you have to do is add some items into the list.

```
List<ClassA> list = new List<ClassA>();
list.Add(new ClassA() { MyProperty1 = 1, MyProperty2 = 2 }); //adding item
ClassA retVal = list.Where(o => o.MyProperty1 == 1).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: While I appreciate the answer I think you have misunderstood me.  The list or model contains data and it returns it to the view.  No data is missing, its only that while debugging most of it is unavailable to view.